# Best way to send a mass amount of text reminders using AWS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to send a massive amount text message reminders that are stored in a MongoDB database that need to be sent at a certain time down to the minute (they will be sent using AWS).

The current idea is to use AWS to have a Lambda worker that gets called every minute by CloudWatch pull out reminders for the current minute and put them into a SQS queue where workers would pull the reminders to send.

The problem is that I am worried reminders will get sent too late either because of the amount of reminders in the queue or because the database of reminders is too big to query fast enough. So the first question is can I query the database say 5 minutes earlier then add them to a queue to be sent at a exact time? I know you can add timers to SQS messages but you can't specify a time, would this be the best way to do it?

Also would it be worth it to keep a database of all reminders that need to happen then move past reminders to a different database after they are added to the SQS queue (I need to save past reminders)? Is this a good way to go about making this system?

Edit: I am currently planning out the development so I do not currently have any bottlenecks. We expect at the busiest time we will have to send 300 to 400 reminders in a minute but the database is estimated to grow about 100 entries a day.

Comment: I'd try to call every 15 or 30 seconds and check what needs to be sent the next minute. If you cant be late think about how you deal with the fact the sms gateway could be not available. Why did you choose mongo as db? I believe dynamo has a trigger for lambda directly.

Comment: I'd like to try and make it as close to possible and in the future it may send other types of alerts that are time sensitive. I chose mongo out of familiarity I will look into dynamo.

Comment: The big question is: does it hurt if you are a minute early? Lambda startup delay is a thing for certain languages and they easily can take minutes ..

Comment: The closer to the correct time the better but early is certainly better then late.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer fully without more information, how big is your scale?, what query are you running to fetch documents?, how long does that query take? what and where exactly is the bottle neck? and more...

Assuming your mongo side flow is perfected and its still too slow you can add a delay to SQS but its capped, from the [amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html):

> The default (minimum) delay for a queue is 0 seconds. The maximum is 15 minutes.

Meaning as long as you can keep the other mongo lambda process under 15min you should be fine.

If you would add more information i'd be glad to give my opinion on it.

Comment: Well I am currently planning out the development so I do not have answers to your questions about what the bottleneck is and what query I'm using but we expect to at the busiest time have to send 300 to 400 reminders in a minuite but the database is estimated to grow 100 entries a day. But a delayed queue would not necessarily mean the jobs are ran at the right time because if I started adding them to a delay queue of 5 minutes each job would become visible 5 minutes after it is added so if it takes 3 minuites to query the db the last jobs would not get done until later then the time required.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of moving past reminders to a different database or a table. This way the query that picks up latest reminders will execute very fast few milliseconds. But to start with a single database with proper indexing will work based on the scale you mentioned(100 entries per day). Also if you are using Lambda itself as a worker to pull messages from SQS and send reminders, it would be more scalable.

Comment: Ok I will keep this in mind thank you. I was planning to use cloudwatch to schedule a job to pull the data out of the database and add them to the SQS queue then have lambda workers pull the jobs out of the queue. This is what you mean right?